# Regex, extracting a list of data from log

Tags: regex

with a log like this:

```
API code n.º 1111111111, registered transaction
NAT Code: 8500/1500
6 value
User code: 51000
Start Time 18-09-2019 22:45:59 CET [18-09-2019 16:45:59 ET]
End Time 18-09-2019 23:00:47 CET [18-09-2019 17:00:47 ET]
  1: cod_user1 (online), 19.236 (99%)
  2: cod_user2 (online), 5.244 (88%)
  3: cod_user3 (online),
  4: cod_user4 (online),
  5: cod_user5 (offline),
  6: cod_user6 (offline),

Queue 542. End transaction.

API code n.º 2222222222, registered transaction
NAT Code: 8500/1500
6 value
User code: 51000
Start Time 18-09-2019 22:45:59 CET [18-09-2019 16:45:59 ET]
End Time 18-09-2019 23:00:47 CET [18-09-2019 17:00:47 ET]
  1: cod_user1 (online), 19.236 (99%)
  2: cod_user2 (online), 5.244 (88%)
  3: cod_user3 (online),
  4: cod_user4 (online),
  5: cod_user5 (offline),
  6: cod_user6 (offline),

Queue 542. End transaction.

API code n.º 3333333333, registered transaction
NAT Code: 8500/1500
6 value
User code: 51000
Start Time 18-09-2019 22:45:59 CET [18-09-2019 16:45:59 ET]
End Time 18-09-2019 23:00:47 CET [18-09-2019 17:00:47 ET]
  1: cod_user1 (online), 19.236 (99%)
  2: cod_user2 (online), 5.244 (88%)
  3: cod_user3 (online),
  4: cod_user4 (online),
  5: cod_user5 (offline),
  6: cod_user6 (offline),

Queue 542. End transaction.
```

There are N iterations and I need extract data in a list mode (separated by tabs), something like:

```
apicode     nat code    value   Start date          End date            Queue
1111111111  8500/1500   6 value 18-09-2019 22:45:59 18-09-2019 23:00:47 542
2222222222  8500/1500   6 value 18-09-2019 22:45:59 18-09-2019 23:00:47 542
and so on ....
```

And I need also extract the complete list of users and status and data, for every iteration of the API code, like this  (separated by tabs):

```
apicode     user        status  data    eff
1111111111  cod_user1   online  19.236  99
1111111111  cod_user2   online  5.244   88
1111111111  cod_user3   online          
1111111111  cod_user4   online          
1111111111  cod_user5   offline         
1111111111  cod_user6   offline         
2222222222  cod_user1   online  19.236  99
2222222222  cod_user2   online  5.244   88
2222222222  cod_user3   online          
2222222222  cod_user4   online          
2222222222  cod_user5   offline         
2222222222  cod_user6   offline         
3333333333  cod_user1   online  19.236  99
3333333333  cod_user2   online  5.244   88
3333333333  cod_user3   online          
3333333333  cod_user4   online          
3333333333  cod_user5   offline         
3333333333  cod_user6   offline
```

Is possible with a regular expression?

What I've got.

https://regex101.com/r/1bpioM/1

I have the first script, I've got the list with substitutions. BUT the script is adding a line break between each row.

```
\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t\10

1111111111  8500/1500   6   51000   18-09-2019 22:45:59 18-09-2019 23:00:47 542

2222222222  8500/1500   6   51000   18-09-2019 22:45:59 18-09-2019 23:00:47 542

3333333333  8500/1500   6   51000   18-09-2019 22:45:59 18-09-2019 23:00:47 542
```

What I have not achieved is the list of users, since the script only locates the first user of each item in the log

Could you help me to revise this?

Thank you

Comment: Which regex-engine are you using? Are you using any specific language or the typical shell commands?

Comment: I need simple regex code for launch on a any regex online web such as https://regex101.com/

Comment: Is the number of users fixed?

Comment: no, is a variable number, from 1 to N

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is like that you can highlight the interesting parts with

```
(?<=API\scode\sn\.º\s)\d{10}|(?<=NAT\sCode:\s)\d{4}\/\d{4}|\d\svalue|(?<=User\scode:\s)\d{5}|(?<=(Start|End)\sTime\s)\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sCET|(?<=Queue\s)\d{3}
```

It select every piece that is followed by specific strings. The "pieces" are formatted like the ones on your file, and so are the "specific strings".
See a better explaination [here](http://regexr.com/4lagq).

Check if it works of your engine, because it uses constructs (positive lookbehind) that are not always compatible

Comment: Is ok, the only problem is the parser doesn't accept this in lookbehind (?<=(Start|End) because is not the same width. If I change with two lookbehind then works. So, how could I format in list mode?

Comment: with this code, the result is one match for every lookbehind, a row for every match, I need a row for every item of log and a "column" for every field. Is possible? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "format in list mode"? Also, regex does not format text: you need something else take the input of the regex and format it, but this would be a whole different question

Comment: In my first message I've put the out format I need. From log I need a list with data (rows and columns)

Comment: Then again, a regex doesn't parse text: it is just a language to tell how to search IN a text. You need some software. Java? awk? sed? C? php? javascript? We know nothing about what you need or what you are using because you just asked for the regex (granting it singlehandedly did everything).
I suggest you make a new question with a more specific request.